# Как заменить содержимое div с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть ссылка и div. Как реализовать замену содержимого div на содержимое ссылки по клику на ссылку с помощью Jquery?

`<a class="a">Текст1</a>
<div class="b">Текст2</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.a').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.b').text($('.a').text());
});
```

Comment: собственно зачем вам `on`? и почему бы не использовать `this` внутри?

Comment: Я вообще не пользуюсь jquery и не знаю как там чо , просто помог человеку!

Comment: А если у меня несколько ссылок с одним классом "a"?И нужно подставлять текст из той ссылки, по которой был произведен клик?Этот скрипт работает, он подставляет весь текст из всех ссылок с этим классом.

Comment: ```$('.a').on('click', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.b').text($(e.target).text());
});```